# Solar charging a lipo battery with ESP8266 as a battery load

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell, esp8266, energy-harvesting, solar-charge-controller

I am trying to add solar harvesting capability to my IoT device based on esp8266. I am using linear charge controller (MCP 73831) with solar input to charge a 500maH lipo battery.

An observation when the device is active (connected to a wifi AP) and solar input is available, the linear charger goes into CC mode even if the battery is fully charged. Possibly because esp8266 draws around 80-90mA of current on average during wifi connection process. (Solar charge current available is around 30-40 mA on average)

Is this safe? can this result in possible overcharging of the battery. More pointers on this will be highly appreciated.

Adding a diagram of the setup:
[image: setup]

Comment: Do you have the ESP8266 directly connected to the battery? If so, why?

Comment: Need a diagram of your setup

Comment: Finbarr, esp is connected to the battery via 3.3v LDO.

Comment: @laptop2d added a diagram of the setup